# split by regex and add matches to dictionary

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, dictionary

first time posting here.

I'd like to 1) parse the following text:`"keyword: some keywords concept :some concepts"`

and 2) store into the dictionary: `['keyword']=>'some keywords', ['concept']=>'some concepts'`.

There may be 0 or 1 '*space*' before each 'colon'. The following is what I've tried so far.

```
sample_text = "keyword: some keywords concept :some concepts"

p_res = re.compile("(\S+\s?):").split(sample_text) # Task 1 

d_inc = dict([(k, v) for k,v in zip (p_res[::2], p_res[1::2])]) # Task 2
```

However, the list result `p_res` is wrong , with empty entry at the index 0, which consequently produce wrong dict. Is there something wrong with my regex?

Comment: You should skip the first item if it is empty. If the match is found at the start of a string, your regex split operation will always yield an empty item at the initial position in the list. You may add `if not p_res[0]:
 p_res = p_res[1:]` to the code.

Comment: Or you may remove the empty first item with [`if not p_res[0]:
 p_res.pop(0)`](https://ideone.com/b7A1aA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.findall` to capture list of groups in a match. And then apply `dict` to convert list of tuples to dict.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'keyword: some keywords concept :some concepts'
>>> dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\S+\s*:|$)', s))
{'concept': 'some concepts', 'keyword': 'some keywords'}
>>>
```

Above regex would capture key and it's corresponding value in two separate groups.

<sub>I assume that the input string contain only key value pair and the key won't contain any space character.</sub>

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/f8Iszd/2)

Comment: Great solution. your assumption correct too. the key'd be single word at most cases or hyphenated words sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace Task1 by this line:

```
p_res = re.compile("(\S+\s?):").split(sample_text)[1:] # Task 1
```

This will always ignore the (normally empty) element that is returned by `re.split`.

**Background: Why does `re.split` return the empty first result?**

What should the program do with this input:

```
sample_text = "Hello! keyword: some keywords concept :some concepts"
```

The text `Hello!` at the beginning of the input doesn't fit into the definition of your problem (which assumes that the input starts with a key).

Do you want to ignore it? Do you want to raise an exception if it appears?  Do you want to want to add it to your dictionary with a special key?

`re.split` doesn't want to decide this for you: It returns whatever information appears and you make your decision.  In our solution, we simply ignore whatever appears before the first key.

Comment: thanks for pointing our the potential exception. I think that'd be handled in pre-processing task. Your solution fixed the issue but i'd have to accept @Avinash Raj answer as his regex is more robust than mine.